# How to use customer_logout event in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer-session

I wanna use `customer_logout` event to un-register data from registry.

Can anybody help?

Comment: what you mean by un-register?

Answer (score 4):

You can use customer_logout event to do that below is sample code write the code in your config.xml

```
   <events>
   <customer_logout>
        <observers>
            <Namespace_Module_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>CustomerLogout</method>
            </Namespace_Module_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
    </customer_logout>
   </events>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, I did same but the method was not getting called.I checked by adding the code in both global and front end sections.

Comment: @PhaniBob i use the event and this worked for me can you write some code of your config.xml that how you use the event

Answer (score 2):

First you need study about magento event/observer from

- [magentoecommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) site
- [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/category/magento/events-observers/)

Here an example :

```
   <global><!-- here global is define the where are you want to fire event. If we make it frontend then it will fire in frontend
    if Fire admin area then it should be adminhtml

 Value: global/adminhtml/frontend
    -->
        <events>
          <customer_logout> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
            <observers>
              <customer_logout_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
                <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
                <class>modulename/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
                <method>FireAndfuncyion</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
              </customer_logout_handler>
            </observers>
          </customer_logout>
        </events>
      </global>
```

when magento is fire an event then it send some parameters to Observer.Using this parameter implement your operation.

Whenever magento fire  `customer_logout even`t then it send `customer data to Observer.`

```
 Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
```

thus we can use  this data.

On observer you can get this parameters value   data

```
<?php
class ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{

    public function FireAndfuncyion(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
           // Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_logout', array('customer' => $this->getCustomer()) );
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    }

}
```